# Mastering both the French r and the German r

Tags: pronunciation, german, french

I have a high level in German and French, but I use a [uvular /ʁ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_uvular_fricative) in French
and an [alveolar /r/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental,_alveolar_and_postalveolar_trills) in German (and in Dutch, my native language).
In German, the alveolar /r/ is mainly used in Bavaria and parts of Switzerland and Austria. Most parts of Germany use a
[voiced uvular /ʀ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uvular_trill) or a [voiceless uvular /ʀ̥/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_uvular_trill).

So there appears to be a **difference between the French /ʁ/ and the German /ʀ/ or /ʀ̥/**, and the difference is subtle enough for people to ask what that difference actually is.
See for example:

- [How is the "r" sound in German different from the French and Spanish ones?](https://www.quora.com/How-is-the-r-sound-in-German-different-from-the-French-and-Spanish-ones?share=1) on Quora;
- [Are the German R and the French R the same?](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120602111413AAZ7FjI) on Yahoo Answers;
- [German R vs. French R](http://how-to-learn-any-language.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=8175&PN=94) on /how-to-learn-any-language.com
- [Does the French R-sound come from Germanic influence?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/21102/13805) on Linguistics SE.

Having learnt French before German, efforts to produce a German /ʀ/ or /ʀ̥/ can easily result in importing the French /ʁ/ into German.
How can this be avoided? **How can one learn to pronounce the French /ʁ/ in French and the German /ʀ/ or /ʀ̥/ in German?**